# how come i can generate keys using bip39 with only one words as seedphrase/mnemonic without any error?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, private-key, mnemonic

Seed phrase/mnemonic is supposed to be 12 words or 24 words but I am able to generate keys with single word seed phrase using bip39 library without any error? what is happening here? how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically just generating a low entropy keypair. There is hard no requirement of 12 or 24 words. More info [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) (word count is not part of the spec).